# Static Property value depends on another Static Property value?

Tags: apex, static

When writing a future method, I wrote 3 static properties for this future method.

Here's an example:

```
global class MyTestClass {
private static Date month1start
{
    get 
    {           
      if (month1start == null){
          integer currentmonth = System.today().Month();
          integer currentyear = System.today().year();
          integer month1=currentmonth;//first month of current quarter        
        if(math.mod(currentmonth,4)==2){
            month1=month1-1;
        }else if(math.mod(currentmonth,4)==3){
            month1=month1-2;
        }
          Date month1start = date.newinstance(currentyear, month1, 1);              
      }            
      return month1start;
    }
    private set;
}
private static Date month2start
{
    get 
    {           
      if (month2start == null){
             month2start = System.today();
               month2start=    month1start.AddMonths(1);   
      }                     
      return month2start;
    }
    private set;
}
private static Date month3start
{
    get 
    {           
      if (month3start == null){
        month3start = System.today();
               month3start=    month2start.AddMonths(1);

          }                     
      return month3start;
    }
    private set;
}

public static void staticmethod(){
    System.debug('month3start: '+month3start);
}
}
```

When I execute anonymous code:

```
MyTestClass.staticmethod();
```

I got error message "System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object"

I thought when accessing "month3start", "month2start" and "month3start" would be created.

Sorry I'm not able to understand this by reading materials online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a silly mistake!

You are creating a new variable here and assigning value to it but the actual month1start is still null and returning the null one.

```
Date month1start = date.newinstance(currentyear, month1, 1);
```

Change the above line to

```
month1start = date.newinstance(currentyear, month1, 1);
```

and you will be fine!

Comment: Your answer might be more useful if you explain and/or link to how properties work.

Comment: You're right! I should update the answer